# Laravel 5.1 randomly dropping session data

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5.1

I have a strange issue with a Laravel 5.1 application.

Intermittently, it’s dropping session data. I’m detected this by writing some middleware that writes the contents of the session for that request to the log file. Although the session ID (`Session::getId()`) doesn’t change, the value of `_token` in the session data retrieved with `Session::all()` *does*.

As I say, this happens intermittently. I can refresh the same URL multiple times, and then randomly on one refresh the session data’s gone, and the `_token` value’s different from the previous requests.

What would cause this? I’ve also noticed the `flash` object isn’t in the “dropped” session data.

Below is a snippet of the log. You can see the content of the `session_data` key randomly changes “shape” in the last two lines, but the session ID remains constant.

Also, not sure if it’s pertinent, but I have [DebugBar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) enabled.

[image: Screen-shot]

**UPDATE:** Through debugging, I’ve found that on some page loads the session is completely *empty*, as in, no `_token` (hence a new one getting generated). Nothing.

Comment: How frequently does this happen? Because I've tried to reproduce this by enabling DebugBar, creating a middleware that logs the session id and data as serialised JSON just like you're doing, then called a route with a view that auto refreshes every second and left it like that for about 10 minutes. But it didn't refresh the CSRF token or drop any session data. This was done with `artisan serve` and the `file` session driver, so you might want to post more information regarding your environment.

Comment: It happens every minute or two. The app’s running under Apache. I can refresh a URL and it’ll randomly lose the data as per the screen-shot after a number of refreshes. There’s no real pattern to it, which is making trying to find the cause difficult.

Comment: My first suggestion is to try to reproduce the problem using on a clean install of Laravel  something along the lines of what I've described in my first comment, to at least see if the problem is with your application code or with something else in your setup.

Comment: Found this question after searching for a similar issue on L4,2. The session will be written when the script finishes. Is there a possibility that the script is simply not finishing, but being killed instead? I've seen that on some VPS servers using byte-cacheing and heavy-AJAX pages - too many rapid requests result in a HTTP500 and the PHP handler dying with a memory violation of some sort. The session would not get written in those instances.

Comment: i have same problem.
1. when response return as view::make(), it work fine.
2. when response return by response()->json() it refresh session._token hash.

Answer (score 3):

1. If you're using the file driver, you could run into race conditions on concurrent requests. The file then gets truncated, Laravel can't read it, so it refreshes the session. Race conditions can also lead to a symptom where something you're putting to the session just doesn't get put. This tends to be random, so it's very hard to debug. According to the Laravel team, this is a known limitation of the file driver and it does not appear to be getting fixed, so I would suggest using a different driver. This would fix your issue of random session refreshes, but it still introduces a possibility of making a change to the session that doesn't get added. As far as I know, at this point with Laravel 5.1, you'll have to manage that yourself.
2. Somehow your session data is too long and being truncated. If you're using the database driver (haven't tested other drivers), and you try to save session data that's longer than the field length, then subsequent requests won't be able to pull from this session, and you'll wind up with a new session. If this issue is happening randomly with very short session data, then it's probably the cause listed above.

Comment: I just spent 2 days tracking this down and #1 was the culprit. For unrelated reasons, we were trying to include a JS file that didn't exist. This had to go through the app/router before it could resolve to a 404, and this was causing the race condition. Removing the link to the bogus js file seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Linux, Try using Redis (http://redis.io) as session / cache manager in laravel. I had some issues in the past with text / cookies and laravel in some servers. When I instaled Redis I had no problems anymore.

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/redis

Comment: Thanks, but an alternative driver doesn’t really solve the problem. Our staging environment is using the file driver, and this where the issue occurs.

Comment: Could you try the Database driver? It will persist in a database table instead, maybe it works.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session

Comment: Been using database driver, and issue is still seen. Not sure if its driver culprint. I noticed this happen often in middleware, if we were to print in blade, Its coming fine. Not sure whats strange thing going on...

Answer (score 0):

Using a different driver like `memcached` did not solve the problem for me.
Here is a package that implements session locking which works and very simple to incorporate in your projects.

https://github.com/rairlie/laravel-locking-session