# Laravel logging users out after x number of requests

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Application has functioned as expected until I added the below route for displaying images:

```
Route::get('/images/workers/{imageName}', function($imageName){
    if(Auth::check()){

        // Intervention using GD does not have functionality for bmp images
        //return \Image::make(getenv('IMAGE_DIR') . $imageName)->response();

        $filename = getenv('IMAGE_DIR') . $imageName;
        $handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
        $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
        fclose($handle);

        header("content-type: image/bmp");

        echo $contents;

    } else {
        return \Image::make(getenv('IMAGE_DIR') . 'denied.png')->response();
    }
});
```

In one of my controllers I obtain records containing links to these images, and display them in a table with pagination. I display 50 records at a time with `<img>` elements to display the images (which are thumbnails for the records). I can usually get the first few pages to display as expected, but then I will start to get my `denied.png` image displaying and once this happens I find that I have been logged out and must log back in.

I read [Andrew's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088764/laravel-5-1-randomly-dropping-session-data) and came to the conclusion that I had a race condition happening that was somehow corrupting the session and causing the account to be logged out. I then created a `sessions` table in my database and changed the session driver in laravel to `database`, however it doesn't look like authentication is using the session driver? Is that correct? If so and this is a type of race condition, how could I go about circumventing it?

Using laravel 5.2.45

**EDIT**

Something else that may be noteworthy, is that this environment is using nginx/phpfpm. Could it be that most of my requests are being processed by one worker thread, but occasionally they are being processed by another and this thread is unaware of the existing authentication session? Or does it not matter which worker thread processes the request via fpm and the authentication session persist across them all?

Answer (score 0):

It appears wrapping this particular route with the web middleware took care of the issue:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('/images/workers/{imageName}', function($imageName){
        if(Auth::check()){

            // Intervention using GD does not have functionality for bmp images
            //return \Image::make(getenv('IMAGE_DIR') . $imageName)->response();

            $filename = getenv('IMAGE_DIR') . $imageName;
            $handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
            $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
            fclose($handle);

            header("content-type: image/bmp");

            echo $contents;

        } else {
            return \Image::make(getenv('IMAGE_DIR') . 'denied.png')->response();
        }
    });

});
```